# Initiating a scrapy crawl as a Django management command

Tags: django, scrapy

I’ve got a project that connects Django and Scrapy where I’m looking to initiate a spider crawl through a Django management command. The idea is to run it periodically via cron. I’m using Django 1.11, Python 3.5 and Scrapy 1.5

Here's the code for my custom management command in the  ‘~/djangoscrapy/src/app/management/commands/run_sp.py’ file

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import os

from django.conf import settings

os.chdir(settings.CRAWLER_PATH)


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        print ('In run_from_argv')
        self._argv = argv[:]
        return self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

When I run $python manage.py run_sp crawl usc

I get this error….

```
In run_from_argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/greendot/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/greendot/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/greendot/webapps/scraper3/src/app/management/commands/run_sp.py", line 15, in run_from_argv
    return self.execute()
  File "/home/greendot/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 314, in execute
    if options['no_color']:
KeyError: u'no_color'
```

My project structure is as follows

```
SRC
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── management
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── run_sp.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py
├── example_bot
│   ├── dbs
│   ├── example_bot
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   ├── middlewares.py
│   │   ├── pipelines.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   └── spiders
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       └── usc.py
│   └── scrapy.cfg
├── example_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
```

I've added the line below to my Django settings file so that when the management command executes, it is in the 'example_bot' directory since the 'scrapy crawl' command is only available within the scrapy project directory, and not in the BASE_DIR.

```
CRAWLER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'example_bot/')
```

I can't seem to get this to work though so any help is much appreciated

Comment: your stack trace doesn´t look complete, is there more to it? I was doing the same thing this week (running scrapy from django)

Comment: there was one more line which I've added